# Pandas DataFrame to Django API

Tags: python, django, api, pandas

I'm using pyodbc + pandas to analyze data, and I'm wondering how to store the final dataframe in Django.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DATABASE;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

qry = "SELECT * FROM SECURITIES"
df = pd.read_sql(qry, cnxn)

*do some manipulation*

df_final

ticker    beta
ABC       1.2
XYZ       0.8
```

Ive got my model and serializer set up, but I'm stuck on how to push the dataframe into this model.

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    beta = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

class TickerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ticker
        fields = ('ticker', 'beta')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from .available import df_available
import sqlite3

engine = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']

# Create your models here.
class Stocks(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    beta = models.FloatField(default=1.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

cnxn = sqlite3.connect(engine)

df_final.to_sql('api_stocks', con=cnxn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: works: `df_final.to_sql('api_stocks', con=cnxn, if_exists='replace', index=False)`

doesn't work: `df_final.to_sql('Available', con=cnxn, if_exists='replace', index=False)`

error:
`Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`